# Python, Как транслировать код python в exe 32 бит на 64 битной системе

Tags: python

Мне надо транслировать python код в exe 32 бит, но у меня 64 битная система.
Долго гуглил чтобы так сделать но ничего не нашёл.
Использую python3.9.1

Comment: Да и в целом перевод в `exe` далеко не всегда работает, если используете не совсем уж стандартные библиотеки, так что задумка в целом не очень хорошая.

Comment: Если не сильно углубляться то создайте виртуалку x32  и в ней сделайте exe. По идее должно работать.